# tinymce pagebreak unclosed div

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce

I use tinymce pagebreak to seperate content and in php side I want to show just second part after pagebreak:

```
$str = '<div>
     <p dir="rtl" style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size:medium;"><!-- pagebreak --></span></p><p>fdsfsdf f sf f s</p></div>'

$arr = explode("<!-- pagebreak -->", $str);
```

and when I want to just use `echo $arr[0]` or `echo $arr[1]` it has unclose `<div>` tag and this will break whole site

Comment: If you are sure that all `$arr[0]` and `$arr[1]` has unclosed `<div>` for all the entries then you can add a `</div>` manually after echoing it else you need to handle some way i.e., to check whether it has unclosed div or not and then do accordingly

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen no I'm not sure and also it may has other unclose html tag that my cuz problem

Comment: Okay, You want to know the way to find whether it has closed div or not. Shall i help you in this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP states that he is unsure on the closed `</div>` I am suggesting this way to handle that

**Step 1 :**

Find whether you have closed `<div>` or not

It can be do by finding the number of occurrence of `div` in the column

```
$occurance = substr_count($arr[0], 'div');
```

**Step 2 :**

If you have even number like 2,4,6 then you can assume that the div is closed else the div is not closed.

```
$occurance = substr_count($arr[0], 'div');
if ($occurance % 2 != 0) {
echo '</div>'
}
```

If it is even number then you can leave as it is. Else add `</div>` to it

Bit more explanation

```
$occurance = substr_count($arr[0], 'div');
if ($occurance % 2 == 0) 
{
// do nothing
}
else
{
echo '</div>';  // adding closed div
}
```

**Note :**

I believe that you are not adding unnecessary div inside your text area

### Update :

After the discussion with [Lajos Arpad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436560/lajos-arpad), I crossed the various fail cases only with `substr_count`

**Fail Cases :**

1. Having improper `<div>` tags

   `<div></div></div><div>`
2. If we have `<div class="foobar">`, then it will not be observed
3. If we have `<div>division by 0</div>` then it will not be observed.

**How to Over come it**

I then have a little think after this conversation and concluded that

There are only one possibility of `open` a div

i.e.,

`<div*`

The divOpen will have `<div>` or `<div class=*** >` or `<div id=***>`

There are only one possibility to `close` a div

i.e.,

`</div>`

**1st Way**

To Count the number of occurance by [subtr-count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

To count the number of `<div` in the page / paragraph to calculate the divOpen

To count the number of `</div>` in the page / paragraph to calculate the divClose

It can be done by

```
$divOpen = substr_count($str, '<div');
$divClose = substr_count($str, '</div>');
```

[Here's the Eval Example](https://eval.in/384973)

**2nd Way**

To Count the number of occurance by [preg-match-all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

To count the number of `<div` in the page / paragraph to calculate the divOpen

To count the number of `</div>` in the page / paragraph to calculate the divClose

It can be done by

```
preg_match_all('~<div\b[^>]*>~', $str, $match);

preg_match_all('~</div>~', $str, $match);
```

[Here's the Eval Example](https://eval.in/384972)

**Note :**

If the input is Bad HTML i.e., Having improper `<div></div></div><div>` it will fail.

Then the step to over come it would be identify the number of properly quoted `<div>` and improperly quoted `<div>`. and try to do replace or remove the wrongly placed `<div>`. So, It is recommended to have a good HTML in database.

Comment: I am not sure your code would handle well cases like <div></div></div><div>. If that is the case, then the number of div occurrences will be correct, however, the html will be invalid.

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes, It would fail in that case. That's why i add a `Note` stating proper usage of div in my answer :)

Comment: Also, if the result contains something like <div>division by 0</div>, you will have a valid html, but the occurrence of div as text will make your solution cry. Why don't you have a divOpen and a divClose array where you store the positions of <div and </div>, respectively? By parsing the positions you would get a better result.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Then i should check for `<div>` and `</div>` Isn't it ?

Comment: You are almost right. You need to check for <div and </div>. <div> will not be helpful, because of possibilities, like <div class="foobar"> will not be observed.

Comment: Yes, this is a really tricky problem. You are on the right track to think about regular expressions. The alternative is to write/use something to generate a tree and validate it. Note, that problems might occur with other tags as well and quotes can be mishandled as well. Your answer has the potential of becoming one of the all-time-great answers on stackoverflow if you provide a nice solution to this.

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes it is, let me write some regex regarding it and give the better solution. Thanks from heart for appreciating :) Starting my first `regex` :)

Comment: I am completely noob with regexp, but if you upgrade your solution then I will probably recommend it whenever someone has the same kind of problem.

Comment: Sure do, Let me give the first try and upgrade the solution :)

Comment: It will take little time to answer as i was in bike, I will give the best as i can in few time :)

Comment: No problem, I have up-voted both the question, which made us having this conversation and the answer, which is already nice and will become much better. Let me know when you edited it.

Comment: @LajosArpad Thanks for mentioning the fail cases, this gave the possible ways to overcome it. However i am still thinking to overcome the improper/bad html

Comment: As I have already mentioned, I am clueless in regex (I am sooo creative and lazy that I always find an alternative so I do not have to learn it). Therefore, if I were to solve this, I would use jQuery.parseHTML (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) to parse the string into an html and see what might the errors be.

Comment: @LajosArpad I have updated the possible way in regex and given eval demo in the updated answer. However, we can detect whether the given html is bad or not through it, but the way to identify the location of bad area and fixing it is still running in my mind, Let me try to give even better if possible [May be a little research i might take ;) ]

Comment: Very nice addition, really in the spirit if Ubuntu